# Is there any limitations on minting token? I can't mint the token that I made anymore

Tags: mint

I have made a token on Solana using dexlab before and the token supply was 100T and I have minted again more token and now the supply are 184T token, I wanna make the total supply like 10 quadrillion but I can't mint anymore

I have tried mint on Dexlab and CLI but it can't mint more supply

Does anybody here know my problem? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

2^64=18446744073709551616 which is around 1.844*10^19, and is the limit of token supply including decimals since the token's supply is stored as a 64-bit unsigned integer in the mint account. The cause of you being unable to mint more tokens might be that.

Relevant documentation: https://docs.rs/spl-token/3.5.0/spl_token/state/struct.Mint.html#structfield.supply

Comment: The token decimal is 5 and now the actual total supply is 184,466,554,885,593 Tokens.. so I can't mint more supply again? Like make it to 1 quadrillion maybe?

Comment: @Dogen Correct. If your token has 5 decimals and the total supply is that 15 digit number, then you cannot mint 1 quadrillion tokens, as the total supply is represented as an unsigned 64-bit integer in the mint account, and 10^15*10^5=10^20>2^64. The maximum supply you can have for this token is 2^64/10^5=184,467,440,737,095.51616 .